# how to draw svg or canvas on image on specific cordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

I have coordinates (x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)(x4,y4) which are selected on a image.I want to draw a canvas(rect) on using cordinates.How to do this?
I have tried using this function, but its not drawing on specific cordinates on a image.

```
                  for(var i=0;i<_self.coordinatesxy.length;i++){
                        fnc( _self.coordinatesxy[i][0],_self.coordinatesxy[i][1],ci)                
                    }
                    function fnc(x,y, ci){
                            console.log(x,y)                    
                    ci.lineTo(x,y);
                    }
                    ci.strokeStyle = 'red';
                    ci.lineWidth = 2; ci.stroke();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We will be able to provide better help with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by 'not drawing on specific coordinates', where does it draw? In general your code seems fine.

```
ci.strokeStyle = 'red';
ci.lineWidth = 2;
ci.moveTo(_self.coordinatesxy[0][0],_self.coordinatesxy[0][1]);    
for (var i = 1; i < _self.coordinatesxy.length; i++) {
    ci.lineTo(_self.coordinatesxy[i][0],_self.coordinatesxy[i][1]);
}
ci.stroke();
```

Comment: it draws below the image.may be issue with placing canvas tag.

Comment: wrap both the canvas and image in a container, and position the canvas in absolute position so it will be placed on top of the image. make sure they have the same width/height.